# Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package::getPackageByUserAgent()

Tags: magento-1.9, php-7

I was getting a 500 error once I moved my magento 1.9 install from an old server to a new server. The old server was running php5 and this one is on 7. I am now getting the following error and I know I have to change some of the code, but I am not sure what:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package::getPackageByUserAgent() must be of the type array, object given, called in /home1/acapps/flagstuff.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Design/Package.php on line 576 and defined in /home1/acapps/flagstuff.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Design/Package.php:586 Stack trace: #0 /home1/acapps/flagstuff.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Design/Package.php(576): Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package::getPackageByUserAgent(Object(Zend_Log), 'design/theme/te...') #1 /home1/acapps/flagstuff.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Design/Package.php(262): Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package->_checkUserAgentAgainstRegexps('design/theme/te...') #2 /home1/acapps/flagstuff.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Design/Package.php(287): Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package->getTheme('template') #3 /home1/acapps/flagstuff.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Design/Package.php(420): Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package->updateParamDefaults(Array) #4 /home1/acapps/flagstuff.com/app/code/core in /home1/acapps/flagstuff.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Design/Package.php on line 586

This is the code that starts on line 586 of Package.php

```php
public static function getPackageByUserAgent(array $rules, $regexpsConfigPath = 'path_mock')

{
        foreach ($rules as $rule) {

            if (!empty(self::$_regexMatchCache[$rule['regexp']][$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']])) {

                self::$_customThemeTypeCache[$regexpsConfigPath] = $rule['value'];

                return $rule['value'];

            }

            $regexp = '/' . trim($rule['regexp'], '/') . '/';

            if (@preg_match($regexp, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
                self::$_regexMatchCache[$rule['regexp']][$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']] = true;

                self::$_customThemeTypeCache[$regexpsConfigPath] = $rule['value'];
                return $rule['value'];
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I needed to change this:

`public static function getPackageByUserAgent(array $rules, $regexpsConfigPath = 'path_mock')`

to this

`public static function getPackageByUserAgent($rules, $regexpsConfigPath = 'path_mock')`

after that, it worked like a charm